# load view within div tag using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my website.i had a situation to load a view within another view.how could i do this.Codeigniter follows the MVC pattern so we cannot directly load the another view without the help of controller.
here is my menuview page

```
<table align="center" width="200" border="0" style="margin-left:160px">
    <tr align="left">
    <td ><input type="radio" id="R1" name="R1" value="1" />PieChart</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="R1" name="R1" value="2" />BarChart</td></tr></table>

<div class="clear"></div>   
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

where the div with id "chart_div" here i want to load another view called chart.php belongs to view.how could i load the chart.php view page when user select radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI lets you return a view as a variable. It is not very common, but you can find information at the very bottom of the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html). You're basically going to need to do something like this:

```
$charDiv = $this->load->view( 'chart', $charDivVars, TRUE );
$this->load->view( 'menuview', array( 'chart_div' => $chartDiv ) );
```

Then, in your view:

```
<div id="chart_div"><?php echo $chart_div; ?></div>
```

Comment: it shows the error message like "  An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: chart_div.php  ". But seems your code gonna load two view . i need when user click the radio button then only load the another view within div tag

Comment: I didn't see the name of your view, so I guess `chart_div`. Your view was named `chart` though, so I fixed that.

Comment: when user tap the radio button then only need to load the another view

Comment: Well, then you're either going to need to ask a question about AJAX or you're going to need to toggle display:none and display:inline.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response