# how to create dynamic content explicitly in the main views on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need help to accomplish a web page contains some existing html page. I need to load my new web page dynamically with many existing html page. And the existing is has an html format with each own assets folder. Thus, I use the CodeIgniter framework as my new main webpage.

My Web folder structure goes like this:

```
Project
|
|-->application
    |        
    |-->controllers
    |-->views
        |
        |-->main.php [Main index file]
        |-->Module01 [sub content (Dynamic) directory of main.php]
            |
            |-->ContentA [Section 1 of Module01]
                |
                |-->story_html5.html [I want to be sub content of main.php]
                |-->mobile [assets of story_html5.html]
                |-->story_content [resources of story_html5.html]
            |
            |-->ContentB [Section 2 of Module01]
                |
```

[image: Web Structure Folder 1]

[image: Web Structure Folder 2]

My main page (template) is `main.php` in the `view` directory. And I want to place the file `story_html5.html` as embedded content in the `main.php` dynamically. So, the content page can change dynamically as the user click any link on the main page. It can be switched into another `story_html5.html` inside another module, or ContentB directory.
And the `story_html5.html` already has resources and assets on it's same location directory (sub directory) named `mobile` and `story_content` directory. It contains some js, CSS and flash files.

The question is, can I load dynamic content (with its resources) which is also reside on the `view` directory with CodeIgniter? Or is there any better way to accomplish this?
I can do this without php / framework using object element like this:

```
<object type="text/html" data="Module01/ContentA/story_html5.html"></object>
```

But I need some security and some URL parameter rules, so I use php framework.

** I've already do dynamic page from the controller for my left menu, as referred from this page: [load view within div tag using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006804/load-view-within-div-tag-using-codeigniter?rq=1)

**====== EDITED ======**

I've thrown this variable from my controller like this:

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('Module01/ContentA/story_html5.html');
```

But the problem is, the page content (story_html5.html) does not load its content resource (js, css and flash files).

Comment: I'm a bit confused and I read this question 2 times. I get that you want to load different "modules" in the view per the user specification and that for some reason your content resources aren't being loaded but I don't see any of your view file code. (1) Why don't you just include the content resource in the say `story_html5.html` resource at the top? (2) if that isn't what you want to do make it a .php file and pass it the variables via the controller e.g. `$this->load->view('Module....', array('css' => 'somecss.css', 'js' => 'somejs.js'))` its essentially the same as (1).

Comment: @Alex thanks for your help, I really appreciate your comment. I finally just move my existing modules into outside of the "application" directory. And then I still using the html element code like this `<object type="text/html" data="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Module01/ContentA/story_html5.html" ></object>` on my `main.php` view side.

Answer (score 1):

I finally able to solve this just by simply moving all of my modules directory outside of the `application` directoy. And then from my view side which is the `main.php` I can call the modules with an `object` element like this:

`<object type = "text/html" data = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Module01/ContentA/story_html5.html"></object>`

So, I don't need to change any code for hundreds of files inside the html modules. It loaded the css and js and other resources, normally.